# Closed form of recurrent arithmetic series summation

Tags: summation, recurrence-relations, closed-form, recursion

Knowing that $$\sum_{i=1}^n i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$
how can I get closed form formula for
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^i j$$
or
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^i \sum_{k=1}^j k$$
or any x times neasted summation like above

Comment: You won't be able to solve this just by using the initial equation.

Comment: Go step by step: $\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^i j=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{i(i+1)}{2}=\frac12\cdot \color{red}{\sum_{i=1}^n i^2}+\frac12 \cdot \sum_{i=1}^n i$. The red colored part cannot be solved with the first formula.

Comment: Use the formulae for the sum of $k^2$ and $k^3$

Comment: Hint: $n={n \choose 1}$, $n(n+1)/2={n+1\choose 2}$. Now have a look at the [hockey-stick identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity).

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Do you mind if I write an answer using this now?

Comment: @PeterForeman No problem, go on :)

Comment: For clarification, I don't mind using any other formula then the one I wrote. My goal however is to compute this programmatically for any given number of neasted summation (let's say at least 5 would be ok). And of course I don't want to use loops unless there is no better solution.

Comment: An interesting question is what happens when we continue the process ad infinitum -- do we get a power series in $n,$ and for what values does it converge?

Comment: @mcpiroman Instead of complaining read the comments and the answers. If you have any specific question you´re welcomed. I´m asking myself what do you expect and what YOU have tried.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $f_k(n)$ be the closed form of the summation nested $k$ times. We know that
$$f_1(n)=\frac12n(n+1)=\binom{n+1}{2}$$
$$f_k(n)=\sum_{j=1}^n f_{k-1}(j)$$
So for the next function $f_2(n)$ we have
$$f_2(n)=\sum_{j=1}^n\binom{j+1}{2}=\sum_{j=2}^{n+1}\binom{j}{2}=\binom{n+2}{3}$$
By using the [Hockey-stick identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity) (credits to Jean-Claude Arbaut).
Similarly for the next function $f_3(n)$ we have
$$f_3(n)=\sum_{j=1}^n\binom{j+2}{3}=\sum_{j=3}^{n+2}\binom{j}{3}=\binom{n+3}{4}$$
So one could conjecture that
$$f_k(n)=\binom{n+k}{k+1}$$
which can be easily proven by induction as follows
$$f_k(n)=\sum_{j=1}^n\binom{j+k-1}{k}=\sum_{j=k}^{n+k-1}\binom{j}{k}=\binom{n+k}{k+1}$$
Hence we have that
$$\boxed{f_k(n)=\binom{n+k}{k+1}=\frac1{(k+1)!}n(n+1)(n+2)\dots(n+k-1)(n+k)}$$

Comment: $\sum_{j=1}^n\left(\frac16n^3+\frac12n^2+\frac13n\right)$: The summands do not depend on the index $j$.

Comment: @callculus Yes, sorry I've corrected it.

Answer (score 5):

> We  can  write  the   last  multiple  sum as
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{i_1=1}^n\sum_{i_2=1}^{i_1}\sum_{i_3=1}^{i_2}i_3}
> &=\sum_{i_1=1}^n\sum_{i_2=1}^{i_1}\sum_{i_3=1}^{i_2}\sum_{i_4=1}^{i_3} 1\\
> &=\sum_{1\leq i_4\leq  i_3\leq  i_2\leq        i_1\leq     n}1\tag{1}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\binom{n+3}{4}}\tag{2}
> \end{align*}
>   In (1)  we  observe the  index  range is  the number  of  ordered  $4$-tuples  with  repetition from a set with $n$ elements resulting in (2).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a combinatorial way of thinking about it: first of all, note that we can go one level deeper and represent the innermost piece ($j$, or $k$, etc.) in your formulae as $\sum_{h=1}^j1$; this means that the formula start to look like $\displaystyle\sum_{m=1}^n1 =n$, $\displaystyle\sum_{m=1}^n\sum_{l=1}^m1=n(n+1)/2={n+1\choose 2}$, $\displaystyle\sum_{m=1}^n\sum_{l=1}^m\sum_{k=1}^l1={n+2\choose 3}$, etc. Now, let's look at what the left hand side is counting. In the first case, we're just counting the number of ways to choose an $m$ between $1$ and $n$ (inclusive); this is, self-evidently, just $n$. In the second, we're choosing a number $m$ between $1$ and $n$ inclusive, again, but then choosing an $l$ between $1$ and $m$; this is exactly the number of ways of choosing *two* numbers between $1$ and $n$, where we don't care about the order — that is, choosing $2$ and $5$ is exactly the same as choosing $5$ and $2$.  Similarly, $\displaystyle\sum_{m=1}^n\sum_{l=1}^m\sum_{k=1}^l1$ counts the number of ways of choosing three numbers between $1$ and $n$, without regard to order; this is because we can sort the numbers we've chosen (since we don't care about order), and then note that the largest can be anywhere between $1$ and $n$, but then the next largest can only be between $1$ and the largest, etc.

Now, the difference between this and regular combinations is that in a regular combination every chosen number must be distinct; but if we have an ordered list $\langle k, l, m\rangle$ of the (not necessarily distinct) numbers we've chosen between $1$ and $n$ then we can turn this into an ordered list of not necessarily distinct numbers between $1$ and $n+2$: let $k'=k$, $l'=l+1$, $m'=m+2$. You should be able to convince yourself that this is a one-to-one correspondence between not-necessarily-distinct choices in $\{1\ldots n\}$ and distinct choices in $\{1\ldots n+2\}$, and the same principle extends to any number of choices.  ([This wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination#Number_of_combinations_with_repetition) has more details).

Answer (score 0):

$$S_{n_2}=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^ij=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{i(i+1)}{2}=\frac12\sum_{i=1}^ni^2+i=\frac12\left[\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}+\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right]=\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{6}$$
and now:
$$S_{n_3}=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^i\sum_{k=1}^jk=\frac16\sum_{i=1}^ni(i+1)(i+2)=\frac16\sum_{i=1}^ni^3+3i^2+2i=\frac16\left[\frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4}+\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{2}+n(n+1)\right]=\frac{n(n+1)}{6}\left[\frac{n(n+1)}{4}+\frac{(2n+1)}{2}+1\right]=\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}{24}$$
and we can see a pattern here. For a series $S_{n_a}$ with $a$ nested summations the following is true:
$$S_{n_a}=\frac{1}{(a+1)!}\prod_{b=0}^a(n+b)=\frac{(n+a)!}{(n-1)!(a+1)!}$$

Comment: What is wrong with this answer?

Comment: I don´t know. Hopefully the downvoter leaves a comment.

Comment: Appart from the notation $S_{n_a}$, looks good. Note also that the last expression is ${n+a\choose a+1}$.